# ngRequired not setting $error property on the form field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a control that is conditionally visible and conditionally required based on the value of another field on the form.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-hide="vm.registration.typeId !== 2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
      <label class='col-md-3' for="dischargeYear">Discharge Year*</label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" id="dischargeYear" name="dischargeYear" 
               class="form-control large-text-form main-input"
               ng-model="vm.registration.dischargeYear"
               ng-required="vm.registration.typeId !== 2"
               ng-class="{'has-error': form.dischargeYear.$touched && form.dischargeYear.$invalid}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, even though the `$validators` has the `required` validator on the `dischargeYear` on the `form`, it never has an error in `$error`. What's also interesting is I have another control that works, and the only difference is `ng-required`; the other control just marks up `required`.

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: have you tried with $scope.apply() after setting a registration.typeId

Comment: No I have @NegiRox, but I can give that a shot.

Comment: i think there is some issue because as soon as you set the flag it will populate for error. see my below answer.

Comment: Those double negatives are crazy. The control is *not* visible when `typeId` is *not*  `2`. The control is required when `typeId` is *not* 2. Ergo the control is required when it is *not* visible.

Comment: @georgeawg you were totally spot on - I had to get a handle on that too. It had been a long day and I think I was too close to everything! :D

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the answer was to use `ng-if` on the surrounding `div` and just a `required` attribute on the `input`. This worked because it removed the element from the DOM when it wasn't needed, and recompiled it when it was.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="vm.registration.typeId === 2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
      <label class='col-md-3' for="dischargeYear">Discharge Year*</label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" id="dischargeYear" name="dischargeYear" 
               class="form-control large-text-form main-input"
               ng-model="vm.registration.dischargeYear"
               required
               ng-class="{'has-error': form.dischargeYear.$touched && form.dischargeYear.$invalid}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This caused the `$validators` and `$error` to get populated and the label to pop.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<form name="myForm">

Click here to make the input field required:

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="setRequired"><br><br>

<input name="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="setRequired">

<h1 ng-if="myForm.name.$invalid">The input field cannot be empty</h1>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's basically the setup I have, but if it's not required, it's also hidden.  Notice the `ng-hide` on the surrounding `div`.

Comment: means you need to hide that div if its not required ?